# Python build-in exceptions swallowed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk, not in log

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It seems Python's built-in exceptions are not printed in the EB [Instance Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console).

For example, the following code of course causes a runtime error:

```
print 'This will be printed'
x = None
if None in 'abcdefg':
    pass
print 'This is never printed'
```

The above code fails (with a TypeError, in this case), but the log (whether accessed via the UI or `cat /var/log/httpd/error_log` on the machine itself) simply ends after the last printed statement:

```
[Mon Mar 21 11:32:37.476732 2016] [:error] [pid 493] This will be printed
```

Where can I find the stacktrace from the built-in exception, or how can I make it appear in the log?

More background: I'm running Flask on Python 2.7.  I have very little experience with EB.